# jsp to wicket page , how to create url using page parameters

Tags: jsp, wicket, wicket-1.6

i am inside jsp page and i want to redirect to a wicket page

for instance :

```
  http://localhost:8080/myWicketApp/myPage/?abc=2&&def=3
```

how can i pass a valid url to wickt where the get params converted to page paramters 
myPage(pageParameters pageParameters){
pageParameters.get("abc");//==2
}

or any other way to pass parameters and create url with parameters

Comment: This works for me: http://localhost:8080/myWicketApp/myPage?abc=2&def=3

Comment: What wicket version do you use @yoav.str ? There is no 1.6 release (1.4 => 1.5 => 6.0)

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned Wicket uses its PageParameters as parameter wrapper. To pass paramaters to your class you have to implement constructor

```
MyPage(PageParameters pageParameters) 
{
   super(pageParameters);
   ...
}
```

When you request an URL, e.g.

```
http://localhost:8080/myWicketApp/myPage/?abc=2&def=3
```

You can reach the parameters by their names or index

```
pageParametrs.get("abc").toString(); // return "2"
pageParametrs.get("def").toString(); // return "3"
pageParametrs.get(1).toString(); // returns "2"
pageParametrs.get(2).toString(); // returns "3"
```

If you want to create the URL

```
// on any Componet
setResponsePage(MyPage.class, new PageParameters().add("abc", 2).add("def", 3));
```

Page parameters is an immutable class used to store/recieve parameters, see http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/request/mapper/parameter/PageParameters.html